# Changing strings on acoustic guitar - any difference in the strings in the package?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, strings

I have bought a package of strings for my guitar. Are there any differences with the strings in the package - yes there is the nylon ones for EAD and the clear ones for GAE, but apart from that?

I have bought Ernesto PALLA and I can see numbers next to the barcode - anything to take into account?

I can see there is a difference in the thickness of the strings, should I just rely on my sight on this - thickest E....E.

Comment: For a named brand of strings, they ought to be marked with the string gauges - the numbers are bigger for the thicker strings. The exact range of the numbers depend whether you have "heavy" or "light" strings but they will vary from about 8 to10, up to about 40 to 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should rely on your eyesight.
Your thickest wound string will be low E.
The next thickest wound string will be A.
The next thickest wound string will be D.
The thickest nylon string will be G.
The next thickest nylon string will be B.
The skinniest nylon string will be high E.